# Measuring the worst-case time for fast data structures

Tags: c++, c, time, benchmarking

I am trying to figure out how to measure the worst-case "update" operation for two data structures in C++.

Both of them have the same amortized (constant) complexity (and, approximately, average operation time), but one works in constant worst-case time while the other is logarithmic (in the number of previous updates).

Both implementations average about 15 million update operations per second, making a single update faster than 0.1ms on average.

I have tried using `chrono::steady_clock` to time a single update, but it is not fine-grained enough. Are there any alternatives that can give a sub-millisecond granularity?

Ideally, I would want to draw a figure of the maximal measured update time as a function of the number of updates and show that my algorithm's time remains bounded.

Comment: "_I have tried using `chrono::steady_clock` to time a single update, but it is not fine-grained enough. Are there any alternatives that can give a sub-millisecond granularity?_" 1) If you are not working on a real-time OS, the OS clock isn't fine-grained enough. 2) Measurements of such small timeframes, can be easily polluted by the scheduler scheduling other tasks instead of yours. To avoid it, you can count multiple update operations, until the total reaches, at the very least seconds, or minutes, and then divide by the count of operations performed.

Comment: Worst-case time is probably going to be hard to distinguish from disturbances like interrupts that also cause big spikes.  Maybe you can characterize disturbances and set some threshold above which you assume it was an interrupt making your code sleep instead of just a slow update.

Comment: What kind of HW are you on?  Do you have access to performance counters, or stuff like Intel-PT with timestamps on each taken branch that would let you record timestamps for each asm loop iteration?

Comment: For many desktop hosts, your program will be swapped out with other programs, including interrupt handlers.  You'll need to find a way to measure without these items or run enough cases that the operating system stuff can be averaged out.

Comment: Note that time complexity does not map well to real time. You may be better of discarding timing and counting touches of the data being operated on.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius - unfortunately, measuring multiple updates together will not allow me to distinguish between two algorithms with similar amortized performance.

Comment: @user4581301 - that is an interesting idea, thanks.